# what file transfer mode should i use when transfering files from windows PC to linux server?

Tags: php, linux, windows

I am using FileZilla for Upload/Download files from my windows PC to server and vise a versa

when i am uploading well formatted PHP file on server and then re-downloading it from server the code is mixed up the format

so can any one suggest me what file transfer mode should i use when transferring files from windows to linux server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can set your ftp client to use `binary transfer mode` all the time

Side note
maybe you need a good text-editor or IDE that can convert between
\r, \n and \r\n.

[image]

Comment: i am already using Dreamweaver for editing PHP/Html code. also can you clarify when to use Binary mode and when to use ASCII and when to use Auto mode?

Comment: see my update. that should help. Use binary mode when you want your files to be left unedited.

Comment: Thanks TLJ for your help